# SharePoint REST API Filter for Createdby

Tags: rest, sharepoint, filter

I have inherited a JSOM app that takes a people picker and is suppose to return all items created by a selected user.

The call is below:

https://sitex/sites/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/CPSEDailyReportPictureLibrary?$expand=CreatedBy&$filter=((CreatedBy/Name eq 'Ken Jasper'))&$orderby=Created desc&$top=40&$skip=0&$inlinecount=allpages

Can you please help. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Field name is not `CreatedBy`, it is `Author`

Try this:

```
https://yoursite/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('CPSEDailyReportPictureLibrary')/items?$select=ID,Title,Author/Title&$filter=Author/Title eq 'Ken Jasper'&$expand=Author&$orderby=Created desc&$top=40&$skip=0&$inlinecount=allpages
```

Comment: A link to relevant documentation and/or a complete solution that includes your suggested changes would go a long way towards helping answer the question, if you don't mind editing your answer.

Comment: I am getting No property 'Author' exists in type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Linq.DataServiceEntity'

Comment: Please let me know what should be the exact API call as I spent an hour trying to replace 'Createdby' with 'Author'  . I am getting this error <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<error xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">
<code/>
<message xml:lang="en-US">No property 'Author' exists in type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Linq.DataServiceEntity' at position 2.</message>
</error>